# Are H1, H2 etc valid inside DLs?

Tags: html, html-lists, html-heading

Can I have heading elements inside definition lists?

Example:

```
<dl>
 <h4> heading </h4>

 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>
 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>
 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>

 <h4> heading </h4>

 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>
 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>
 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>

</dl>
```

It seems to work as expected in my browser :)

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input  is the authority.

Comment: Browsers have never strictly adhered to standards, therefor they are not the authority on what is "valid". They might however dictate what works or what is accepted. If we had truly strict standards I imagine 70+% of the web would be inaccessible.

Comment: Which is why browser error-handling has remained. Personally, I'd rather use valid code, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No; the *only* elements that might be valid within a `dl` are `dd` and `dt`.

The reason it may appear to work is error handling by the browser, which is both unpredictable and, so far as I can tell, mostly undocumented and therefore should *not* be relied upon.

Though interestingly, as Šime Vidas notes in the comments (below), Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera and Internet Explorers 7 and 9 don't correct the structure and allows the heading elements to remain within the `dl`. Which strikes me as being weird.

It is, though, while tolerated, still invalid. Whether or not you choose to respect that validity is, of course, optional.

References:

- [`dl`, at the W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#edef-DL).

Comment: Interestingly, Firefox will keep the structure in tact (the H4 are not stripped out of the DL). **Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/R5KPq/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: really? I'm genuinely surprised. All versions of Firefox, or a particular incarnation?

Comment: @Anna: was what sarcasm? I hadn't intended anything I've written to be taken that way, so, on my part, no.

Comment: @DavidThomas Well, then you'll be even more surprised to hear that this behavior is cross-browser `:)` (I tested FF, Ch, Sa, O, IE9, IE7). The browsers just don't seem to care about the H4's in the DL.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: ...I feel slightly disappointed in browsers right now. =/

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can use the [w3c markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) in direct input mode to check code snippets.

Browsers are VERY tolerant of bad html, and not conforming to the rules, even though it works now, might mean your page/layout breaks with a future browser update.

I added the required other elements to get your code to validate as noted below.  Complains about exactly what David Thomas says.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>asdf</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <dl>
                 <h4> heading </h4>

                 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>
                 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>
                 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>

                 <h4> heading </h4>

                 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>
                 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>
                 <dt> title </dt> <dd> content </dd>
            </dl>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add 2 dt tags one with a class

```css
dt.heading {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt class="heading">Heading</dt>
  <dt>milk</dt>
  <dd>white discharge</dd>
</dl>
```

lets you have multiple  after each other since multiple terms can have the similar if not the same definition. like wise you can have multiple  since a term can have a few different meanings. 
And even thou you are changing the way it looks via CSS this wont be a true Heading and will porb get skipped by search engines etc... maybe have a hidden h1 tag with seo content

Comment: is it an answer or a question?